# How to tell whether a graphics card supports audio over HDMI?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, desktop-computer

I want to connect up my desktop PC to a TV via HDMI for watching video on, in addition to a normal (DVI) desktop monitor. Ideally, I would like the audio and video to go through the HDMI cable to the TV.

I found the [GeForce 9600 GT](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814162033), which comes with an SPDIF cable, but how can I tell if it supports passing audio over HDMI?

Also, are there any websites for comparing graphics cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly a comparison site, but this subset of the Overclockers forums is a good place to start :

http://www.ocforums.com/forumdisplay.php?s=7aaf6be00b03ff9de939a156306f6025&f=7

As for the Geforce 9600 supporting HDMI w/Audio, here are 3 that do :

http://ixbtlabs.com/articles3/video/g94-3-p1.html

ATI and NVidia cards should all have this now unless the manufacturer removes it in some editions.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I decided to get the ATI Radeon 5750 in the end. I read that all new ATI cards supported HDMI audio, but unlike nvidia cards they take the audio through the PCIe slot without hte need for an extra SPDIF cable.